# Building a tool to identify the user agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, user-agent, amazon-athena

Any supporting tool that we can quickly identify the user agent of the requests made by offending IP addresses on the CloudFront access logs with help of AWS Athena.

Comment: How do you classify as offending?

Comment: I've seen requests coming in using Googlebot on CloudFront access logs, but when I check the IP addresses it's of a different subnet and not of google.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution to handle the automation of blocking security threats, Amazon do have a pre-built solution for bad actors that covers a number of attacks that are performed against your applications.

By using [AWS WAF Security Automations](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/aws-waf-security-automations/) you can have logs scanned and validated for potential behaviour that is identified. This is done by Lambda crawling your CloudFront/ELB logs using Athena. If it identifies a bad actor it would add their IP address to an IPSet that blocks them from accessing your application.

It also adds functionality for a honey pot URL that when accessed will block the user-agent of the bad crawler.

If you're looking for a solution to just browse your logs you can use [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html) to query your CloudFront logs for user-agents and their associated IP address.